# Get sub-categories of parent with flat catalog enabled Magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, flat-catalog

I have the following code in a phtml fill that is called in a static block and produces a list of sub-categories for the parent. It **currently does not work when flat catalog is enabled**. Can anyone suggest an update to **get this code to work with flat catalog enabled**?

**CURRENT CODE IN CMS>STATIC BLOCK**

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html/categoryblockssteve.phtml"}}
```

**CURRENT CODE IN TEMPLATE/PHTML**

```
<?php  


$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context')->getRequest();
//echo $request->getFullActionName();
if($request->getFullActionName() === "catalog_category_view"){ ?>

    <?php    
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
    /*print_r($category->getData());
    exit();*/
    ?>

    <?php if($category->getDescription()) { ?>
             <?php echo $category->getDescription(); ?>
             <?php /*
                <h1><?php echo $category->getName(); ?></h1>
                <p><?php echo $category->getDescription(); ?></p>
                 */ ?>
    <?php } ?>

    <div class="categor_list row">
        <ul>
            <?php

            //print_r($category->getData());
            //echo $category->getEntityId();


            $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $object_manager = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category->getEntityId());
            $testse = $object_manager->getChildrenCategories()->getData();

            //exit();
            /*$sublist = $category->getChildren();
            $testse  = explode(",",$sublist);*/
            /*print_r($testse);
            exit();*/
            foreach ($testse as $subids) {

                $_objectManagers = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

                $object_managers = $_objectManagers->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($subids['entity_id']); ?>

                <li class="col-md-3">

                    <div class = "cate_name">
                        <a href="<?php echo $object_managers->getUrl(); // URL  ?>" alt="<?php echo $object_managers->getName(); // Name ?>">
                            <?php echo $object_managers->getName(); // Name ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "cate_img">
                        <a href="<?php echo $object_managers->getUrl(); // URL  ?>">

                            <?php if($object_managers->getImageUrl()) { ?>
                                <div class ="img"> <img src="<?php echo $object_managers->getImageUrl(); //Img Path ?>" alt="<?php echo $object_managers->getName(); // Name ?>"></div >
                            <?php }/* else{ ?>
                                <div class ="img"> <img src="<?php echo ""; //Thamnel img ?>"></div >
                                    <?php }  */?>

                        </a>
                    </div>
                </li>

            <?php     } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('all_cat_bottom')->toHtml();?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Above code is working with objectmanager or not?

Comment: Hi Rakesh, above code does work - but does not work if flat catalog is enabled.

Comment: U got ur answer @YorkieMagento?

Comment: Have you faced any error after enable flat category and flat catalog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get  child categories, you can use `getChildrenCategories()` which will  also work with **Flat settings**.

But also note that, if flat is enabled, then you don't need to bring disabled category  in frontend

Please modify your phtml file like this

---

```
<?php  


$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$request = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context')->getRequest();
//echo $request->getFullActionName();
if($request->getFullActionName() === "catalog_category_view"){ ?>

<?php    
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
    echo $category->getName();
    $SubCategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();


?>

 <div class="categor_list row">
        <ul>
            <?php
            if($SubCategories){
            foreach ($SubCategories as $SubCategory) 
            {

                $_objectManagers = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

                $SubCategoryOb = $_objectManagers->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($SubCategory->getId()); ?>

                <li class="col-md-3">

                    <div class = "cate_name">
                        <a href="<?php echo $SubCategoryOb->getUrl(); // URL  ?>" alt="<?php echo $SubCategoryOb->getName(); // Name ?>">
                            <?php echo $SubCategoryOb->getName(); // Name ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "cate_img">
                        <a href="<?php echo $SubCategoryOb->getUrl(); // URL  ?>">

                            <?php if($SubCategoryOb->getImageUrl()) { ?>
                                <div class ="img"> <img src="<?php echo $SubCategoryOb->getImageUrl(); //Img Path ?>" alt="<?php echo $SubCategoryOb->getName(); // Name ?>"></div >
                            <?php } ?>

                        </a>
                    </div>
                </li>

            <?php     } ?>
            <?php  }  // end of f($SubCategories) ?>
        </ul>
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('all_cat_bottom')->toHtml();?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the use of ObjectManager, try using this code **vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Navigation.php at line 187**

```
$categories = $this->_catalogLayer->getCurrentCategory()->getChildrenCategories();
```

Comment: Thanks John, unsure where I'd apply that code in the above... not sure if you can help further please?

Comment: Inside which block is your code located?

Comment: Hi john, the code is in 'categorylist.phtml' and that file is called in a static block.

Comment: Any further assistance you can give John - about where to place your code in the above? Thank you.

Comment: Change your block class by `{{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" template="Magento_Theme::html/categoryblockssteve.phtml"}}` and inside categoryblockssteve.phtml put this code:

`$subcategories = $block->getCurrentCategory()->getChildrenCategories();`
`var_dump($subcategories);`

Comment: Hi Jonathan, and where would I add the second part of the code exactly please?

Comment: You can place it where you want to show it in your phtml file.